# Managing Go dependencies on git

Tags: git, go, dependencies

I develop and maintain my Go project in the following directory:

```
PROJECT_DIR=$GOPATH/src/github.com/<USERNAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/main.go
PROJECT_DIR=$GOPATH/src/github.com/<USERNAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/<APP-1>
PROJECT_DIR=$GOPATH/src/github.com/<USERNAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/<APP-2>
```

But this way I can only track changes in my project and I cannot track dependencies and their versions.

I was wondering if there's an automated way of cloning all the dependencies using the version that my project is using and not the latest commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [Glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide).

Glide provides simplified Go project management, dependency management, and vendoring.

Glide basically changes your $GOPATH on the fly and keeps copies of your dependencies in a local structure instead of the global structure that is customary for a standard Go environment.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a promising tool.